# Jquery generating html codes from C# method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Basically I have a C# web service method that helps to generate HTML code and return it as a string. Now I would like to grab the HTML string from this method and replace a particular div.

```
function replaceHTML(ID) {
    var gID = ID; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        contentType: //what should it be,
        url: "the method location",
        data: {"ID" : gID },
        dataType: //what should it be,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#Div ID').empty();
            $('#Div ID').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

What should be the content Type and data Type? Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Well it all depends on what your web service is providing you and since we cannot see the web service call,  we cannot tell you.

In every average web service it should be specified what type of data it communicates with, whether json, xml, or plain text.

Usually though, it will be xml unless something else is specified because web services are SOAP based and are xml formatted, but you should check your web service or share it's code with us.

Answer (score 0):

`contentType` is the type of data you send to the server, so it'll be `application/json` in your case. Not nessecary to provide that info though, jQuery will detect it based on the contents of `data`.

`dataType` is the type you expect the server to return, so you set it to `text/html`.

Also, see:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you :).

```
 function replaceHTML(ID) {
      var gID = ID; 
     $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      contentType: 'text',//what should it be,
      url: "the method location",
      data: JSON.stringify({"ID" : gID }),
      dataType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",,
      success: function (data) {
        $('#Div ID').empty();
        $('#Div ID').html(data);
    }
 }
```